# How to put condition IF ELSE inside .map in React JS

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, object-object-mapping

I am new to React Js. IF ELSE condition inside the map gives me error.

I want to put IF ELSE condition inside map. I don't want to use **Ternary Operator** if **IF ELSE** is possible.

```
class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        //codes
    }

    testFunction = () => {
        //postDetails is something fetch from the server

        let tableDetail;
        tableDetail = Object.keys(postDetails).map((i) => (
            let val;

            /* I dont know how to achieve this part  */
            if(typeof postDetails[i].comment ===  'string'){
                val = <div>A String!</div>
            }else{
                val = <div>Not a string!</div>
            }
            /* I dont know how to achieve this part  */

            <>
                {val}
                // other codes ..
            </>;
        ));

        return tableDetail;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <>
            <h3>Table</h3>
                {this.testFunction}
            </>
        )
    }
```

Comment: aybe what you are looking for is `filter`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

Update your testFunction with

```
testFunction = () => {
        //postDetails is something fetch from the server

        let tableDetail;
        tableDetail = Object.keys(postDetails).map((i) => {
            let val;

            /* I dont know how to achieve this part  */
            if(typeof postDetails[i].comment ===  'string'){
                val = <div>A String!</div>
            }else{
                val = <div>Not a string!</div>
            }
            /* I dont know how to achieve this part  */

            <>
                {val}
                // other codes ..
            </>;
        });

        return tableDetail;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is missing a `return` which is implied when using `()` but needs to be made explicit when using `{}`:

```
testFunction = () => {
        //postDetails is something fetch from the server

        const tableDetail = Object.keys(postDetails).map((i) => {
            let val;

            if (typeof postDetails[i].comment === 'string') {
                val = <div>A String!</div>
            } else {
                val = <div>Not a string!</div>
            }

            return (<>
                {val}
                // other codes ..
            </>);
        });

        return tableDetail;
    }
```